# Why are my avocado leaves burning at the end?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, container-gardening, avocado

I have about 5 avocado plants grown from seed stage in containers. 2 are close to 2.5 years old and 3 are about a year or 1.5 years old.

The 2 oldest ones are not doing so well but the youngest ones have grown fairly tall and so I was thinking they're healthy. However, one of them shows some sort of burning marks. Any idea what may be going on?

*On the other one they look brown and so half the leaves dry off. But they don't look like in the picture below.*

[image]

Comment: When/how you replaces the soil in the pot? Which fertilizer did you use? To me it seems a lack of nutrients (or problem on roots).

Comment: I loosened the soil some months ago. Over the winter I didn't do a lot of watering (it was cold this year in San Francisco Bay Area). It may have been nutrients too. I have used coffee grinds, orange peels and egg shells at roughly once in 2 weeks since the start of spring.

Comment: I specifically thought coffee grinds may help for the `N` component of `NPK`.

Comment: NPK are not the problems (IMO). I think more about Iron or other "less important" element. But coffee grids can be a problem. They are very acid, and so they could block many nutrients.